# PyTorch equivalent of tf.dynamic_partition

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I need to use an equivalent of `tf.dynamic_partition` in PyTorch. Is there anything with similar functionality in PyTorch or other library or is there a simple and clever way to code it for PyTorch and work fast?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can iteratively create boolean masks for unique indices:

```
import torch


# partitions should be integer-like types
def dynamic_partition(
    data: torch.Tensor, partitions: torch.Tensor, num_partitions=None
):
    assert len(partitions.shape) == 1, "Only one dimensional partitions supported"
    assert (
        data.shape[0] == partitions.shape[0]
    ), "Partitions requires the same size as data"

    if num_partitions is None:
        num_partitions = max(torch.unique(partitions))

    return [data[partitions == i] for i in range(num_partitions)]
```

And example taken from [`tf.dynamic_partition`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dynamic_partition) documentation:

```
partitions = torch.tensor([0, 0, 1, 1, 0])
num_partitions = 2
data = torch.tensor([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])

dynamic_partition(data, partitions, num_partitions)
```

Which gives the same results as the example, namely:

```
[torch.tensor([10, 20, 50]), torch.tensor([30, 40])]
```

Comment: Just had to deal with this problem as well. Two remarks to the line: `num_partitions = max(torch.unique(partitions))`. You shouldn't need the unique before taking the max, right? Also, you probably want to add 1 to `num_partitions`, otherwise the last partition will be missing, i.e. this line should be `num_partitions = max(partitions) + 1`. Also found a faster way to do the same computation, will post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative and for bigger tensors slightly faster implementation. This uses the [degree function from PyTorch Geometric](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/utils/degree.html) to compute the partition sizes, if you don't want to have PyTorch Geometric as a dependency, you can simply copy this function from the link.

```
from torch_geometric.utils import degree
import torch

def stack_dynamic_partitions(tensor, partition_ids, num_partitions=None):
    '''
    Torch implementation of `tf.ragged.stack_dynamic_partitions`.
    '''
    sortidx = torch.argsort(partition_ids)
    partition_sizes = degree(partition_ids, dtype=torch.int32).tolist()
    partitions = torch.split(tensor[sortidx], partition_sizes)

    if num_partitions is not None:
        add_tail = num_partitions - len(partitions)
        assert add_tail >= 0
        partitions = partitions + tuple([[]] * add_tail)

    return torch.nested.nested_tensor(list(partitions))
```

Here is a comparison to the runtime of the implementation (called `dynamic_partition`) that Szymon provided in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64157099/9891955):

```
n_partitions, n_dims = 100, 1000
partition_ids = torch.randint(n_partitions, size=(n_dims, ))
tensor = torch.rand(n_dims)

# benchmark execution time
%timeit dynamic_partition(tensor, partition_ids)        # 1.41 ms ± 3.56 µs per loop
%timeit stack_dynamic_partitions(tensor, partition_ids) # 222 µs ± 301 ns per loop
# test if results are the same:
assert list(map(sorted, dynamic_partition(tensor, partition_ids, n_partitions))) \
       == list(map(sorted, stack_dynamic_partitions(tensor, partition_ids, n_partitions)))
```